# Rot and polyalphabetic ciphers in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.x, caesar-cipher

[I'm writing a "crypto library"](https://github.com/Shifterovich/Crypto) and gradually adding algortihms. Now it's just ancient cryptography, but I'm going to expand the library.
It doesn't depend on any external libraries.

```
class Crypto():
    def __init__(self, rotInt=3, letters=list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")):
        self.letters = letters
        self.length = len(self.letters)
        self.rotInt = rotInt
    def rot(self, string, rotInt, letters, length): # To decrypt, use a negative number
        result = []
        for letter in string:
            if letter == " ": # Skip spaces
                result.append(" ")
            else:
                letterIndex = letters.index(letter)
                resultIndex = letterIndex + rotInt
                resultIndex = resultIndex % length-1
                result.append(letters[resultIndex])
        return "".join(result) # Return result as a string
    def getRotArr(self, string, negative=False): # Negative is for decryption
        result = []
        for char in string:
            if negative:
                result.append(0-(self.letters.index(char)+1))
            else:
                result.append(self.letters.index(char)+1)
        return result
    def polyalphabetic(self, string, rotArr, letters, length):
        result = []
        rotArrIndex = 0
        for letter in string:
            if letter == " ": # Skip spaces
                result.append(" ")
            else: # Spaces would mess up rotArrIndex
                if rotArrIndex > len(rotArr)-1: # Repeat when end of rotArr is reached
                    rotArrIndex = 0
                rotInt = rotArr[rotArrIndex]
                letterIndex = letters.index(letter)
                resultIndex = letterIndex + rotInt
                resultIndex = resultIndex % length
                result.append(letters[resultIndex])
                rotArrIndex += 1
        return "".join(result) # Return result as a string
```

Comment: I feel like the obligatory "You should not roll your own crypto libraries" warning should be put here, because using your own implementation of preestablished crypto while fun or good for a quick exercise of skills usually results in some 'holes' in the mix.  So, obligatory warning about rolling your own crypto.

Comment: @ThomasWard This isn't supposed to be a crypto lib to use. Just a personal challenge, "can I code a crypto lib that can .....".

Comment: Yes, I know, but that's why I said "while it can be fun or good for a skills exercise" in my previous post.  It's just an obligatory warning to ship with everything (so that others who may think "This guy's cool for writing his own crypto library for things" won't go using it.)  It's a standard 'obligatory warning' to the world, is all, wasn't implying you're going to be using it in production :)

Comment: @ThomasWard Or worse, "Hey, this guy can write his own crypto lib and it looks simple, what if I wrote my own for this website I was assigned, too" :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Handling exceptions

If you create library user should be aware what is going wrong if he uses it in the wrong way.

```
def rot(self, string, rotInt, letters, length): # To decrypt, use a negative number
    result = []
    for letter in string:
        if letter == " ": # Skip spaces
            result.append(" ")
        else:
            letterIndex = letters.index(letter)
```

Here, you will receive `IndexError` which is not very informative, probably you would like to make your exceptions for such situations.

### Performance of string concatenations

As you can see from [this post](https://waymoot.org/home/python_string/), most efficient methods are using `list`, `cStringIO` and list comprehension with `str.join`. I recommend you to rewrite your `rot` method to use list comprehension and make all required checks in the beginning of the method.

### Sanity defaults

```
def rot(self, string, rotInt, letters, length)
```

`length` parameter is just a length of the `letters`, so it can be computed in the method.

Because `rot` method is not the static method, you already have initialized class instance so you can use `letters` array received in `__init__` method in case if the user does not provide `letters` to the `rot` method itself.

For an example, you can write something like:

```
def rot(self, string, rotation_index, letters=None):
    letters = letters or self.letters
    length = len(letters)
```

### Data structures for characters set

Storing characters set in the form of the `list` in order to use `index` method every time you what to figure out a position of the element is not the best choice in case of performance. You should probably use additional `dict` for excample:

```
index_of = dict([(e, i) for i, e in enumerate(letters)])
```

You will get `dict` with keys of your letters and values - their positions in the letters iterable. So you can find out position and find is character found in your characters set with

```
<character> in index_of
index_of[<character>]
```

Comment: **Exceptions**: Good point
**Performance**: I'll take a look on that, thanks
**Defaults**: I tried `def rot(self, string, rotInt, letters=self.letters, length)` and it didn't work (obviously, I just tried it) and forgot to tweak the args.
**`index_of`**: Cool trick.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SamuelShifterovich it does not require to pass defaults direct into method declaration string. You can just leave them with `None` by default and make all the checks in the method body.

Comment: Yeah, what I was going to do.
`, letters=None, .....):
letters=self.letters if letters == None else letters`

Comment: @SamuelShifterovich probably you would like to use `or` statement instead.

Comment: Could you provide an example please?

Comment: Dictionary comprehensions are a thing, so there is no need for an intermediate list. You can either use `dict((e, i) for i, e in enumerate(letters))` or `{e: i for i, e in enumerate(letters)}`.

Answer (score 5):

`rotInt`, `letters`, `length` are defined in class. Use it.

Instead of `for loop` use `map`.

```
def rot(self, string, letters=None, rotInt=None):
    if letters is None:
        letters = self.letters
    length = len(letters)
    if rotInt is None:
        rotInt = self.rotInt
    return ''.join(map(lambda letter: letter in letters and letters[(letters.index(letter) + rotInt) % length] or letter, string))
```

**and or**

It's like `bool ? a : b` in `C` / `C++`. It's equivalent to:

```
if bool:
    return a
else:
    return b
```

Comment: I don't understand the `and` and `or` statements here, could you please explain them?

Comment: So in this context it's equivalent to `return letters[(letters.index(letter) + self.rotInt) % self.length] if letters[(letters.index(letter) + self.rotInt) % self.length] else letter`?

Comment: Yes, but only if `string` contains only letters from `letters`.